# How to get placeholder value using assert_selector in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

How do I get the placeholder value from an input bar using `assert_selector` in rails ?

```
<input placeholder="hello world"  value="<%= params[:query] %>" required>
```

I want to check is placeholder has `hello` in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `xpath` and verify that there's an `input` element whose's placeholder `contains` 'hello'

```rb
assert_selector(:xpath, './/input[contains(@placeholder,"hello")]')
```

if you want to check exactly an input with id

```rb
assert_selector(:xpath, './/input[@id="input_id"][contains(@placeholder,"hello")]')
```

im not sure there's a helper method that check regex something like `~= /.*hello.*/`, if you want to do that, you still have another choice

```rb
placeholder = find('#input_id')['placeholder'] # or use :xpath
assert_match /.*hello.*/, placeholder
```

Answer (score 2):

While the answer by Lam Phan does answer the question, resorting to writing XPath queries when CSS has what you need isn't usually the best idea from a readability/understandability perspective.

CSS has a number of attribute selectors, the most useful for testing usually being

- = matching
- *= containing
- ^= begins with
- ~= whitespace separated matching

You can see the full set at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

In this case that means you could do any of

```
assert_selector('input[placeholder*="hello"]') # contains 'hello'
assert_selector('input[placeholder~="hello"]') # contains the word 'hello'
assert_selector('input[placeholder^="hello"]') # starts with 'hello'
```

Another option would be take advantage of the fact that the Capybara :field selector has a `placeholder` filter - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L34 - which takes a regex - so you could do

```
assert_field(placeholder: /hello/)
```

which is the same as

```
assert_selector(:field, placeholder: /hello/)
```

Comment: nice, i tried `~=`, but i used to that operator with regex, so i have never tried with string "hello". Anyway, your answer should be the accepted one.